# Change stored procedure to be used for Autofill in a generic handler based on a checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I have a handler that is used for autofill based on a term that is written in an input textbox. I have no problem getting the term and execute my stored procedure in realtime based on what is input in the textbox. But I want to execute a different stored procedure based on a checkbox next to the input textbox. The main problem is that the autofill is executed from within an IHttpHandler and I seem to be unable to send a single string with the name of the stored procedure to .ashx from the web form backend.

1. I tried sending the name of the stored procedure from web form backend.
2. I tried sending any data from the webform backend depending on if the checkbox is checked and then use either stored procedure based on a string in an if-else statement( using Session, and Redirect-Request)
3. I tried using json to send that data and test if =! null.
4. When I use  Response.Redirect("FoodHandler.aspx?param=Search4") when I click on the checkbox I get redirected to the page where the stored procedure is executed and I just see a whole array of strings.

My aspx backend:

```
    public partial class SearchPageWithDynamicSQL : System.Web.UI.Page
       protected void Page_Load(object food, EventArgs a)
       {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            checkbox2.Checked = false;
            checkboxhidden.Value = "Search3";

        }

     }
    public void Check_Clicked(object check, EventArgs c)
    {
         if (checkbox2.Checked)
           {
               StringA = "Search4";
               Session["param"] = "Search4";
           }
           else
           {
            StringA = "Search3";
            Session["param"] = "Search3";

             }
           checkboxhidden.Value = StringA;         
       }
```

My handler:

```
        public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
         {

      public string blarny { get; set;}
      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
       {


        blarny = context.Session["param"].ToString();

        string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
        List<string> listFOODNAME = new List<string>();

        string cs = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStr"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(blarny, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@term",
                Value = term
            });
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                listFOODNAME.Add(rdr["Long_Desc"].ToString());
            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listFOODNAME));
```

My frontend:

```
       <div class="col-xs-7">
                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control"
                            id="inputLong_Desc" placeholder="Search for food" />
                    </div>
<div class="container" style="position:relative;top: 20px; left:60px" id="checkboxy">      
               <asp:HiddenField ID="checkboxhidden" runat="server"/>
               <asp:CheckBox id="checkbox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Text=" Search only basic foods." TextAlign="Right" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"/>
                       </div>
```

I expect my autofill to work like that : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGpsk.jpg
and I will be able to switch the stored procedure by a checkbox.
When I use 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Search4", con);
It is working fine.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have added

```
   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

in my aspx file and

```
    public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

in my handler, to send data.